# How to have and update a varying number of variables in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, warning-messages

The OP in the question,
[How to return the unevaluated variable names from a list of variables which have been declared](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/how-to-return-the-unevaluated-variable-names-from-a-list-of-variables-which-have),
raised a side issue in an edit, whose solution seemed far afield of the main question.  I thought I would post my take on the question and self-answer, too.

The question is how to have an indeterminate number of variables in a `Manipulate`, each controlled by a slider ***and*** be able to update these values in the code of the `Manipulate`, say, by some numerical routine such as [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html).  There are several Q&A on a coding a variable number of variables (see below), but none I could find also addressed updating the indefinite number of controls.

Here is a example, modified from the linked question, that has a variable number of sliders.  The sliders appear to work, but the button that executes `FindFit` causes errors and the `model[]` function is not plotted, even on the initial evaluation.

```
ClearAll[testplotfit, model, a, b];

data = Table[{x, 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 - 10 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];

model[v_, terms_, x_] := FromDigits[Reverse@Array[v, terms], x];

SetAttributes[testplotfit, HoldRest];
testplotfit[terms_, data_] :=
 Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Dynamic[Button["Compute",                    (* FindFit[]  button *)
      Block[{x}, With[{sol = FindFit[
           data,
           model[b, terms, x],
           Transpose@{Array[b, terms], Array[a, terms]},
           x]},
        Do[a[i] = b[i] /. sol, {i, terms}]]]
      ]],
    Show[                                        (* plots: *)
     Plot[                                       (*   model *)
      model[a, terms, x] /. 
       Array[HoldPattern[a[#]] -> a[#] &, terms],
      {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]},
      PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose@data],
     ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],           (*   data *)
     ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
     ]
    }],
  Evaluate[                                      (* controls *)
   Sequence @@ Table[With[{i = i}, {{a[i], 1, Subscript["a", i]}, -10, 10, 
       Appearance -> "Open"}], {i, 2}]]
  ]
```

Example:

```
testplotfit[2, data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What would be even better is if I could vary the number of `terms` with a slider and have the number of sliders change automatically.

---

A variable number of sliders and other controls comes up in several Q&A (and there are more):

- [Manipulate with variable number of sliders plus variable number of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35076/manipulate-with-variable-number-of-sliders-plus-variable-number-of-functions)
- [Variable number of controls in manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59826/variable-number-of-controls-in-manipulate)
- [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders) (answers only in terms of `DynamicModule` and not `Manipulate`)
- [Mathematica Manipulate with macros AND variable number of controls (persistence desired)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/mathematica-manipulate-with-macros-and-variable-number-of-controls-persistence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ClearAll[testplotfit];
testplotfit[terms0_, data0_, maxterms_: 10] :=
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Plot[
    model[a, terms, x] /. Array[HoldPattern[a[#]] -> a[#] &, terms],
    {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]},
    PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose@data],
   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
   ],

  {{a, a}, None},            (* {a,a}  initializes  a=a  instead of  a=0  *)
  {{data, data0}, None},     (* only one copy of data is stored *)
  {{terms, terms0}, 1, maxterms, 1},
  Dynamic@ Column@ Table[
     With[{i = i},
      Control[{{a, a, Dynamic@Subscript["a", i]}, -10, 10, 
        Manipulator[Dynamic[a[i]], ##2, Appearance -> "Open"] &}]
      ],
     {i, terms}],
  Dynamic[Button["Compute",
    Block[{x, b}, With[{sol = FindFit[
         data,
         model[b, terms, x],
         Transpose@{Array[b, terms], Array[a, terms]},
         x]}, (* TBD: test  FindFit  succeeded *)
      Do[a[i] = b[i] /. sol, {i, terms}]]]
    ]],
  Initialization :> (Do[a[i] = 0., {i, maxterms}])
  ]
```

Example:

```
testplotfit[4, data]
```

[image]

**Remarks:**

A major problem is that control declarations of the form `{a[1],..}, {a[2},..}` etc. results in the expressions `a[1], a[2],...` being replaced by symbols of the form `$nnn$$` where `nnn` is some serial number. These replacements are done literally and lexically throughout the `Manipulate` code, so that expressions like `a[i]` and `a[#]` can never refer to the control variable that is constructed. That is why `Plot` and `FindFit[]` did not work in the OP. Note I avoided such declarations above.

I localized several variables (`a`, `b`, `x`, and `data`) for security. Also the use of `data` in the `Manipulate` means the data set (the argument `data0`) is stored in only one place in the `Manipulate[]` output, instead of being copied into all the references.

I used a trick, `{{a, a}, None}`, which subverts the default initialization `a = 0` by initializing `a` to the uninitialized `a`, a symbol.